# Can I check the dependencies of a stored procedure with other database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Thank you for reading.

```
Temp_server
 - Temp_db1
   . Table : Temp_table
   . stored procedure (they refer Temp_table of Temp_db1)
 - Temp_db2 
   . stored procedure (they refer Temp_table of Temp_db1)
```

Assume that:

- there is a server (called `Temp_server`)
- there are two databases (called `Temp_db1`, `Temp_db2`)

In `Temp_db1`, there is a `Temp_table` and some stored procedures that refer to `Temp_table`.

In this situation, I can view the list of stored procedure which refer to `Temp_table`.

But, in SSMS, it shows only the stored procedure of `Temp_db1`. This means, if there is a stored procedure that is saved on `Temp_db2` and refers to `Temp_table` of `Temp_db1`, it doesn't show up.

Can I view this, too, somehow?

Comment: AKAIK, the dependency graph in SSMS only works for dependencies within the same database. You should avoid cross-database dependencies because they will prevent you picking up your on-premise databases and moving them up into the cloud (Azure DB, AWS RDS, etc.).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning. Thank you for reply. You means, on SSMS, we can't check it. is it right?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I view this, too, somehow?

You can use [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

It shows you dependencies in other databases and even other(linked) servers.

Here is an example when it shows up my historical triggers that writes to another database, Storico.

You can see also test_powershell stored procedure that uses xp_cmdshell from master
and sp_write_execution_log procedure that uses loopback server to execute another sp, sp_write_execution_log_lnk.

[image: sql_expression_dependencies]

Comment: Thank you for reply, but in your image, there are many db name such as master, Storico, but in my db, it shown only 1 db name, and it is based on what schema i choose (ex, USE Storico) How can i view all of it?

Comment: There is no dependence on schema in the result, but the result is shown for objects that you examine in current db.  If you don't see other databases in referenced_database_name why do you think you should have them? I know that all my historical triggers writes in other db made for this purpose, but if there is no need to write to other db why should you have the dependencies in other databases?

Comment: Maybe it is wrong schema arcitecture. But it can't fix because it is already big db.. and the problem is that, in my question, if i modify the `Temp_table` of `Temp_db1`, it will be affect on stored procedure of `Temp_db2`, but i can't know about it.